# Rotations and Shifts in the f-GARCH News Impact Curve

Tags: r, garch

I am using the beautiful "rugarch" package and presently have an issue concerning the interpretation of two asymmetry parameters: `eta11` and `eta21`.

As per the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/rugarch.pdf), `eta11` and `eta21` stand for the rotation and the shift parameters respectively of the family-GARCH nested model news impact curve (NIC).

The package vignette ["Introduction to the rugarch package"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) says that rotations are the main source of asymmetry for big shocks while shifts are the main source of asymmetry for small shocks.

Suppose then this is the coefficient matrix of my estimated MA(1)+AVGARCH(1,1) model with GED errors.

```
           Estimate   Std. Error     Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.007389067 0.0003317894 0.000000e+00
ma1    -0.039530532 0.0050175914 3.330669e-15
omega   0.003378155 0.0011845764 4.347480e-03
alpha1  0.312554942 0.0486658077 1.340761e-10
beta1   0.772007322 0.0304194057 0.000000e+00
eta11  -0.480489955 0.1109057794 1.474820e-05
eta21   0.415200036 0.0645903270 1.291172e-10
shape   0.837323483 0.0760468102 0.000000e+00
```

And this is the plot of the related NIC.

[image]

So, my questions are:

1) What is the financial interpretation of the eta11 and eta21 asymmetry coefficients that I estimated for the above model?

2) How can I compute the impact of positive vs. negative shocks on the volatility of the above model since there appears to be some asymmetry?

I know this may sound a trivial question to you. But I am a statistical modelling rookie and sometimes I cannot find my answers but through your help. So, thank you in advance for your comments.

Comment: I have a feeling that it will be difficult to get an answer here. I used to answer a lot of GARCH questions but am less active presently, and I have no experience with news impact curves, so it would require quite an investment of time to learn that and then write an answer. Maybe you could try on Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange?

Comment: The fact is that I cannot find even other theoretical/empirical studies/blog posts/any references that could help me figure out the real meaning of the two parameters. It's a curious issue. But maybe you're right: I should try also on the Quantitative Finance section. I'll do now.